# Excel 2013 - Why are some blank cells acting as "0" and other blank cells acting as ""?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

The formula I'm using in column J is `=IFERROR(IF(B1>0,H1*I1,""),"")`. In columns H and I, most of the entries are blank (not zero), and J calculates 0. In row 23, J changes to calculate "" while B is still > 0. If I try to multiply H22 by I23, I get an error, and when I go to the calculation, it's trying to multiply (H22)"0" x (I23)"". I have no idea why it stops referring to blank cells as zero in that row, they're all the same data type (General). I tried changing them all to Number, but it didn't change anything.

I understand that empty cells are different than zero-valued cells, but both cells are blank and one is calculating as empty and the other is calculating as zero and I don't know why.

With "Show Formulas" deactivated: 
[image: Picture with values]

With "Show Formulas" activated: 
[image: Picture with formulas]

Comment: Could you provide a sample or screenshots about your problem?

Comment: Your general formula calculates based on everything being in row 1.  The problem you describe has the `H` and `I` cells in different rows.  If that isn't the cause, we would need to see what's actually there.

Comment: [Picture](https://imgur.com/P2Zohdg)

My issue is that in cell J22, the formula calculates to zero because it views H22 and I22 as "0". But then in J23, the formula calculates to #VALUE because it views H23 and I23 as "". There should be no difference between cells H22 and H23, but one is "0" and the other is "".

Comment: Please add the images directly in your question, not the comments. Someone will inline it for you.

Comment: I added links to the images, but I do not have enough reputation to post them as pictures.

Comment: @Frank,, your Formula sometimes returns `Zero` bcoz few Cells in `H & I` are `Blank` so that Excel considers them as `0*0=0`. But for others returns `Blank` since few cell in `Column B` are `Blank` itself, so that when Excel Checks for example `B4>0` the Formula returns `No` ,, since `B4` is `Blank` mean is `Zero`,, but since you have used `IFERROR` so the Excel settles it to `Blank` instead of `Zero`.

Comment: @Frank,, if you want to make a common result, for example If `B1>0 and H1, I1` have value but not `Zero` then Calculate and return Value like the First one **3690** otherwise  return either `Zero or Blank` , you can use this Formula,, `=IF(ISBLANK(B1),"",IF(AND(ISBLANK(H1),ISBLANK(I1)),"",IF(ISNUMBER(B1),H1*I1,"")))`        for **BLANK** and `=IF(ISBLANK(B1),0,IF(AND(ISBLANK(H1),ISBLANK(I1)),0,IF(ISNUMBER(B1),H1*I1,0)))` for **ZERO**.

Comment: @Ralesh S,, The formula is working the way I want it to when the cells in column B are blank. If I wanted those cells to be Zero when B was blank, I would just set the false value to be zero instead of "". There will never be data in columns H or I if B is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `""` is text and cannot be used as a number.
Trying to use it in direct arithmetic will cause the dreaded `#VALUE!` error.
However, most functions will ignore such values.
And, yes, this is inconsistent.

To avoid the error you should therefore use a function.
For example, the
[PRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/product-function-8e6b5b24-90ee-4650-aeec-80982a0512ce).

When multiplying a number with an empty value, PRODUCT will ignore
the empty cell and return the other non-empty cell as its value.
If this is not what you want, use the ISNUMBER function similar to:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(A1);A1*B1;0)`.

Comment: I understand the difference and why I can't use "" in a formula. I'm trying to determine why Excel is treating two adjacent blank cells as two different values. One is "0" and the other is "", and they're both formatted identically.

Comment: They are most probably not identical. One might be truly empty while the other was assigned `""`.

Comment: to check out what type are a value in a cell could use =TYPE(A1) will show you the type of value in cell A1, reference https://support.office.com/en-us/article/type-function-45b4e688-4bc3-48b3-a105-ffa892995899

Comment: Ok so they're definitely different types, one is a number and one is text, but why? And how do I change the type from text to a number? I changed the number format setting and it did not fix it.

Comment: The `=CODE(A1)` formula will return a `#VALUE!` if the cell is truly empty, otherwise a number which is the ASCII character number used in `=CHAR(?)`. What does CODE return for the two cells?

Comment: =CODE returns #VALUE! for both cells. =TYPE returns number for one blank cell and text for the next blank cell.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I went to each cell that was assigned "", even though the cell looks blank, and hit the delete key. I hadn't tried to do this before since there wasn't anything (that I could see) in them. I reread your "...while the other was assigned "" ".

Anyways, deleting the blank contents fixed it, but I don't really understand how they could be blank and contain "".

Comment: Excel is that way, over-complicated and inconsistent. Apparently the cell was assigned something in the past and ended up marked as assigned a string but without a value (or CODE would have returned something). Hitting Delete caused a re-check of the cell contents, and it was then discovered that it's not really assigned anything.

Comment: Thanks for the help/explanation.

Yeah, when I highlight the cells that are blank that are assigned "", it gives me a count in the bottom right of the window as "number of cells that contain data". The count doesn't count the actually-blank cells.